# make Nodejs script make http request through eth0:0 and eth0:1

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs script and i want to send requests to read websites, using different virtual IPs (preferably rotates through IPs), my IPs are assigned to eth0:0, eth0:1 and so on ...

I tried to make a local proxy with rotating IPs but seems to be much harder task, but if nodejs does not have any viable option, please refer me to some documentation of how to make my own local proxy with rotating IPs please

Comment: Do `eth0:0` and `eth0:1` have separate IP addresses?

Comment: yes, they have separate IP addresses, sorry i thought that was clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are making outbound http requests, you can set the `localAddress` option to the IP address of the adapter you want to use.  The `localAddress` option is available in the common ways of making an outbound connection such as [`socket.connect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_options_connectlistener) to [`http.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) to [`request()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback).

It appears that cloudscraper uses the `request-promise` library which is derived from the `request()` module mentioned above.  It may be that you can use the `options` argument for cloudscraper and specify the `localAddress` option there and it will pass it through to `request-promise` which will pass it through to `request` which will pass it through to `http.get()` which will pass it through to `net.connect()`.  You will need to try it to see if it works.  I don't have any way to try it here.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more please, I use cloudscraper to get the html of the website, how does that apply there ?

Comment: @harryking - Now, you're changing the question and making it about cloudscraper which is something that is not mentioned at all in the question.  I've answered the question you originally asked.  If you look at the [cloudscraper code](https://github.com/codemanki/cloudscraper/blob/master/index.js), it appears that it uses the `request-promise` module which supports the `localAddress` option.  So, perhaps you can just use the `localAddress` option in the cloudscraper options argument.  You will have to try that yourself.

Comment: just a quick question about localaddress, in the http.get or request options ( i m not sure about socket.connect), we set the IP address not the eth0:0, how will the script knows what ethernet to use? does ubuntu routes that by nature ? or is there something else needs to be configured ?

Comment: @harryking - I don't know how it works inside the OS, but the idea is that you specify the IP address you want to send from and some low level code in either nodejs or the OS picks the right network adapter that matches that.  It's a TCP connection so the language you speak here is IP addresses, not adapter names.

Comment: @harryking - Did this work for you?  Did you try it?

Comment: added it like this and got an error :
 var sendReq = request.get({
       url: url,
       headers: {
          'User-Agent': User_Agent_String},
       strictSSL: false
    });
 sendReq = sendReq.localAddress('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')

error :
TypeError: Property 'localAddress' of object #<Request> is not a function

Comment: @harryking - Per the documentation, `localAddress` is an option you pass to `request.get()`, not something you set later.  It's shown in the list of options [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback).  It appears you are not attempting to use it correctly.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes is i got it going finally, your answer was correct all along ,thanks heaps again